# Disable eslint completely in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I want to disable eslint and prettier completely in my React app project. These errors are causing havoc in development.

There are errors coming because of eslint/prettier/jsx-ally and I am stuck with it -

Visible, non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at least one keyboard listener                                                                                                     jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events

```
          <span onClick={() => connect()}>
            <Link
              to='/'
              className={location.pathname.toLowerCase().includes('/docs') ? 'active' : 'passive'}
            >
              {'     '}Connect API
            </Link>
          </span>
```

.eslintrc.js :-

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:react/recommended', 'airbnb', 'prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: false,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 13,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react'],
  rules: {
    semi: 'error',
    'no-console': 'warn',
    'no-undef': 'error',
    'no-unused-vars': 'error',
    'no-use-before-define': 'error',
    'newline-before-return': 'error',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'linebreak-style': 'off',
    'prettier/prettier': 0,
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/function-component-definition': 'off',
    'jsx-quotes': ['error', 'prefer-single'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control': 'off',
  },
};
```

.prettierrc.js :-

```
module.exports = {
  "semi": true,
  "tabSize": 2,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "endOfLine": "auto"
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to keep Eslint checks activated, because they can be very valuable. However, if you are especially blocked by the rule `jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events` then you could add `"jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off"` into your `.eslintrc.js` in the "rules" property.

For your particular problem:

It seems like you are using a `<span>` tag with a click handler. This is untypical as Browsers expect these elements to be not interactive. You could try putting the `onClick` property on the `<Link>` component, if this supports it or you add `role="button"` to your `<span>` to indicate that it is an interactive element.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this line in your `.env` file:

```
DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
```

Also you can just disable prettier extension.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that these rules exist because javascript is not a statically typed language and these rules help you avoid common issues in your application and also help make your code more readable.

`jsx-a11y` is a ruleset for accessibility which will help make your application more accessible to people with disability.

If you still want to just get rid of the linters, you can remove them from your build steps/scripts or just remove these plugins from eslintconfig: `'plugin:react/recommended', 'airbnb', 'prettier'`